# Python, copy only directories

Tags: python, directory, copy, subdirectory

I have a program that has a list of some files. I have to copy only the directories and the subdirectories from the list to a specified directories and don't need to copy the files. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
def copiarDirs():
items = list.curselection()              
desti = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
for dirs in os.walk(items, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs: 
    #for i in items :                       
        aux=root+"/"+list.get(i)            
        tryhard=("cp "+str(aux)+" "+str(desti))
        os.system(tryhard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

def copyDirs(source, destination):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for f in files:
            dir = destination + os.path.join(subdir).split(':')[1]
            if not os.path.exists(dir):
                os.makedirs(dir)

sourceDir = 'D:\\Work\\'
destDir = 'D:\\Dest\\'
copyDirs(sourceDir, destDir) #calling function
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. 
In addittion i only have to copy the curselection directories